# Adding a "fill" attribute to a data.tree object for use in collapsibleTree in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, data.tree, collapsibletree-r

We've been using dataframes with `collapsibleTree()` to make interactive, nice looking dendograms of hierarchical systems.  The issue we have though is that it's difficult to get the customization we want when using a dataframe and it seems from the `collapsibleTree` documentation that using data.tree structure provides for more flexibility.  For example, if we want to color specific nodes with a dataframe, we need to do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.tree)
library(collapsibleTree)

colors <- rep('gray', 15)
colors[1] <- 'red' # root
colors[3] <- 'red' # child we want to emphasize
colors[15] <- 'red' # grand child we want to emphasize

original_data_frame %>% 
  collapsibleTree(
    hierarchy = c("level_2",
                  "level_3",
                  "level_4",
                  "level_5",
                  "level_6",
                  "level_7"
    ),
    root = "level_1",
    fill = colors
  )
```

This isn't really a good solution, especially when the resulting tree has hundreds or more nodes or higher levels of hierarchy.

I saw that in data.tree, I should be able add arbitrary attributes but this doesn't seem to be working, at least it's not having the desired affect I want it to have:

```
original_as_tree <- original_data_frame %>% 
    mutate(pathString =
           paste(
             level_1,
             level_2,
             level_3,
             level_4,
             level_5,
             level_6,
             level_7,
             sep = "/"),
           pathString = str_remove_all(pathString, "/NA")) %>% 
  as.Node()

original_as_tree$color <- "gray"
original_as_tree$Boat$color <- "red"

collapsibleTree(original_as_tree,
                fill = original_as_tree$color)
```

This just colors each node "gray" (or red if I did `original_as_tree$Boat$color`).  Ideally, I'd be able to assign colors programmatically with some sort of `case_when` or `ifelse` call.

Here's the dput of my example data:

```
structure(list(level_1 = c("Sea System", "Sea System", "Sea System", 
"Sea System", "Sea System", "Sea System"), level_2 = c("System Engineering", 
"Boat", "Boat", "Boat", "Boat", "Boat"), level_3 = c("Core Systems Engineering", 
"Auxiliary Systems", "Total Ship Integration/Engineering", "Electric Plant", 
"Hull Structure", "Hull Structure"), level_4 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), level_5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), level_6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    level_7 = c("GREENLAND ENTERPRISES, INC.", "3M PURIFICATION INC.", 
    "5TH AXIS, LLC", "901 D, LLC", "A. M. CASTLE & CO.", "A.M. CASTLE & CO."
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I'm little late to the party on this one! I just used the acme data included in data.tree as an example. I'm using data.table out of preference but the same idea applies with dplyr - one way to get what you want would be to create a column specifying colors before converting to a data.tree.

```
library(data.tree)
library(data.table)
library(collapsibleTree)

# example df
data(acme)
acme_df = ToDataFrameTree(acme, "pathString", "cost") 
acme_dt = as.data.table(acme_df)

# create a color column
acme_dt[, color := ifelse(is.na(cost), "red", "blue")]

# convert dt to Node
acme_tree = as.Node(acme_dt, "cost", "color")

# collapsible tree
collapsibleTree(acme_tree, fill = "color")
```

Hopefully this is helps!